# Google indexing and url redirection

Tags: indexing, search-engine, redirect

Google use a websites url along with its content when indexing it. With that in mind is it possible to redirect http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com/something, so that Google will use the latter when indexing it?

My attempt at redirection has not changed the url used by Google for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [canonical URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) on `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/something`

Search engines (and maybe other clients) treat that as the “real” URL for your content.

Comment: I have tried a combination of canonical URL and http permanent redirect (which that Wikipedia link mentions as being preferred by Google), but still the URL shown on the Google result pages is "www.example.com" instead of "www.example.com/something".

Comment: When did you make that change? Keep in mind that Google won’t update their index “over night” just because you changed something, it might take up to a couple of weeks. Anyway, Google Webmaster Tools should be able to give you more information about what Google sees for your site.

Comment: The combination has been in effect for weeks.

Comment: Have you checked with Webmaster Tools?